# Why does this `int` have the wrong value?

Tags: c++, hex, posix, byte

Not sure how else to put that, but I'll start off with a code snippet and output:

```
uint32_t expires;

cout << "Expiration bytes: " << setfill('0') << hex
     << setw(2) << (unsigned short)rec[keyLen+4]
     << setw(2) << (unsigned short)rec[keyLen+5]
     << setw(2) << (unsigned short)rec[keyLen+6]
     << setw(2) << (unsigned short)rec[keyLen+7] << endl;

expires = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&rec[keyLen+4]);

cout << "Expiration: " << (long)expires << endl;

cout << "Hex: " << hex << expires << endl;
```

Outputs:

```
Expiration bytes: 00000258
Expiration: 258
Hex: 258
```

I can confirm from other parts of the program that examining and outputting the hex representation of bytes works as expected, and that those are indeed the bytes in the byte stream (sent from another application).

Now, I would be able to understand a bit better if `expiration` just held some nonsense, because that would mean there's some egregious error (probably involving pointers). But this... this is clearly just spitting out the hex value as if it were a decimal, and that's plain *wrong*.

To make matters more confusing, this works at another point in the program:

```
fullSize = ntohs(*(uint16_t*)&buff[0]);
```

With a byte value of 0x0114, `fullSize` will contain the value 276.

So the question is, what the heck is going on here? How is it possible for an int to be *wrong*?

Comment: Your program exhibits **undefined behaviour** at almost every step.

Comment: While I'm not condoning any of your code, let me add that you could simply say `cout << "Old Expiration: 0x" << hex << setw(8) << *(uint32_t*)&rec[keyLen+4] << endl;` at the top of your program to try and print the value before the conversion.

Comment: Please, specify the type of varible rec?

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak: From the printing code you can infer that its a type any value of which can be expressed with two hex digits...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Can you explain why it is undefined?

Comment: @KerrekSB: We should not have to make guesses.

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak: As was stated, it's a byte/char stream. It was gotten from recv; the data is a custom header.

Comment: Aren't three downvotes a bit too harsh for a question which contains a code example and where the OP has tried to investigate the matter and to describe his though process? Yes the code is not stand alone and there is UB and whatever but this doesn't seem justified ...

Comment: @Francesco I'm more concerned about having "undefined behaviour in almost every step". Partially because there's, like, 2 steps, but much of what I've got I pulled from answers on this very site. If I'm doing something wrong, I'd like the details, ya know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cout << "Expiration: " << dec << (long)expires << endl;` will output decimal, otherwise the last setting (`hex` or `dec`) will still be in effect.

Comment: This explains the problem _and_ how to fix it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 16):

`hex` is sticky, so unless you reset it, `cout` will continue to output things in hex.

You can reset it by issuing sending `std::dec` to the stream. Alternatively you could build a more advanced mechanism that would store the original state and restore it afterwords.

Comment: Doesn't deserve a score of 11 (wth?!) unless you explain how to reset it.

Comment: Is there any way to tell what line last left the cout stream in the hex state?  Let's say that you have a large project that has hundreds of files and it so happens that one of the cout statements leaves the cout in the std::hex state.  However many other ostreams are used so you can't simply break on the appropriate function.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since you never switch `cout` back to decimal output, *all* of your outputs are in hex, even the output of `cout << "Expiration: " << (long)expires << endl;`.